# Uncaught Error: Undefined constant AF_NET - PHP Socket

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, undefined, php-socket

*Hello everyone, I got AF_NET error using php socket.
I try to found on multiple post, but all enable this `extension=sockets` or `extension=php_sockets.dll` in their php.ini and work.

I enable both and separately on my php.ini of my XAMPP in Windows, I resolve the `Undefined socket_create` but now I get this error and nothing works. Try to restart Xampp also.

If someone know and can help me please I would be very happy  !

AF_NET undefined
[image: Error message]

Here is my code below to create a php socket :
[image]

Comment: Sorry I can't edit my post, I don't know why. But *Hello Everyone !

Comment: Perhaps you mean `AF_INET` instead? Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell. You should be able to [edit] your post to add the code

Comment: Thank you !!! Indeed I write AF_NET instead of AF_INET . Thank you very much !!! You can post it as an answer and I select as the answer of this thread if you wish